# FXCop Rule validation for Constructor Parameters

Tags: c#, fxcop

I am trying to write a FXCop rule to validate the following kind of a code,

```
namespace ClassTarget
{
    public class Class1
    {
        private static readonly Type DeclType = System.Reflection.MethodBase.GetCurrentMethod().DeclaringType;
        public void StartWatchingForUpdates1()
        {
            using (new TraceGuard(DeclType,"StartWatchingForUpdates1"))
            {
                Console.Write("Test");
            }
        }

        /// <see cref="IAutomaticUpdaterBackendHelper.StopWatchingForUpdates"/>
        public void StopWatchingForUpdates2()
        {
            using (new TraceGuard(DeclType, "StopWatchingForUpdates2"))
            {

            }
        }

    }
}
```

Here I have to validate if the method name and the string called inside the TraceGuard constructor ( using (new TraceGuard(DeclType, "StopWatchingForUpdates2"))) are same or not.

I am able to catch the Traceguard Constructor from my FX cop rule but not able to find what is the 2nd parameter passed to it as method name.

Can anyone help me on this?

Comment: Check out http://fxcopcontrib.codeplex.com/SourceControl/latest#Dev/FxCopContrib/RegularExpressionDoesNotCompile.cs which checks the Regular Expression string passed to the Regex constructor.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for the help, though it was not the exact solution but it took me to the exact one. Thanks a lot!!

Find my code below,

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Microsoft.FxCop;
using Microsoft.FxCop.Sdk;


namespace MyCustomRule
{
    public class MyCustomRule : BaseIntrospectionRule
    {
        private TypeNode m_ArgumentException;
        string errorMessage, methodName;
        Boolean problemyn;
        public MyCustomRule() :
            base("MyCustomRule", "MyCustomRule.Connection", typeof(MyCustomRule).Assembly)
        {
        }

        public override ProblemCollection Check(Member member)
        {
            Method method = member as Method;

            MetadataCollection<Instruction> enumerator = method.Instructions;
            methodName = method.Name.ToString();

            StatementCollection stmt = method.Body.Statements;
            try
            {
                problemyn = false;
                VisitStatements(stmt);

                if (problemyn)
                {
                    Resolution resolu = GetResolution(new string[] { method.ToString() + errorMessage });
                    Problems.Add(new Problem(resolu));
                }
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(e);
            }
            return Problems;
        }

        public override void VisitExpression(Expression expr)
        {

            Construct cnstruct;
            InstanceInitializer instInit;

            int i = 0;

            cnstruct = expr as Construct;
              if (cnstruct == null)
                return;

            instInit = (InstanceInitializer)((MemberBinding)cnstruct.Constructor).BoundMember;

            foreach (Expression operand in cnstruct.Operands)
            {
                if (instInit.Parameters[i].Name.Name == "strMethodName")
                {
                    Literal lit;
                    String litString;

                    lit = operand as Literal;
                    if (lit == null)
                        continue;

                    litString = lit.Value as String;
                    if (litString == null)
                        continue;

                    if (methodName == litString )
                    {
                        break;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        problemyn = true;
                        errorMessage += methodName + " " + litString;
                    }


                }
                i++;

            }



        }
    }
}
```